# how to send encoded data from python to nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to send some string data from **Python3** to **nodeJs**. The string is **Korean** characters and I am encoding it to **utf8**.(Cause I don't know other ways sending data safely.) When I send(from python) it is ByteStream and in nodeJs I receive it as Array. I convert this Array to String. But now I cannot decode string back to original Korean characters.
Here are some codes I am using.

python

```
input = sys.argv[1]
d = bot.get_response(input)
data = str(d).encode('utf8')

print(data)
```

nodeJs

```
var utf = require('utf8');
var python = require('python-shell');

var pyt = path.normalize('path/to/my/python.exe'),
        scrp = path.normalize('path/to/my/scriptsFolder/'),


    var options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: pyt,
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: scrp,
        encoding: 'utf8',
        args: [message]
    };

    python.run('test.py', options, function (err, results) {

        //here I need to decode 'results'
        var originalString = utf.encode(results.toString());// that code is not working for me

    });
```

I have used several libs like utf8 to decode but didn't help.
Can someone please give some idea how to make it work.

**EDIT**

I have to edit with some more info.
I have tried @smarx approach but did not work.

I have two cases:

**1.** if I send data as string from python here is what I get in nodeJs `b'\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95\xed\x95\x98\xec\x8b\xad\xeb\x8b\x88\xea\xb9\x8c? \xec\x9d\xb4\xed\x9a\xa8\xec\xa2\x85 \xea\xb3\xa0\xea\xb0\x9d\xeb\x8b\x98! \xeb\x8f\x99\xec\x96\x91\xeb\xa7\xa4\xec\xa7\x81\xec\x9e\x85\xeb\x8b\x88\xeb\x8b\xa4`

**2.** if I encode data and send. I get `�ȳ��Ͻʴϱ�? ��ȿ�� ������! �`

Comment: What does `python.run` do?

Comment: It runs python script.

Comment: I meant more specifically than that. :-) Can you share the code for `python.run`?

Comment: You edited the code but still didn't share `python.run`.

Comment: Try `print(d.decode())` in your Python code. I don't know what `bot.get_response` is doing, but it looks based on your output like it's returning `bytes`. Break the problem into two pieces: first get your Python code to actually print what you want, and then make sure your JavaScript code receives the output as-is.

Comment: bot.get_response returns class_name type. I need to use str() function to convert it to string. Whatever type I send from python(string or byte) I receive string in node js. If I send string I get unreadable characters. If I send byte I get b'\ed9\uf7  string.

Comment: I don't know what that type is. But the byte sequence you shared prints out fine if you decode it first (on the Python side).

Comment: In Python, this evaluates to `True`: `b'\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95\xed\x95\x98\xec\x8b\xad\xeb\x8b\x88\xea\xb9\x8c? \xec\x9d\xb4\xed\x9a\xa8\xec\xa2\x85 \xea\xb3\xa0\xea\xb0\x9d\xeb\x8b\x98! \xeb\x8f\x99\xec\x96\x91\xeb\xa7\xa4\xec\xa7\x81\xec\x9e\x85\xeb\x8b\x88\xeb\x8b\xa4'.decode() == '안녕하십니까? 이효종 고객님! 동양매직입니다'`

Comment: Maybe if you tell me what library you're using (where does `get_response` come from), I can help more.

Comment: `get_respond` returns `'안녕하십니까? 이효종 고객님! 동양매직입니다'` and I am encoding it to send to nodejs. Because I want send utf8 data and receive utf8 data. But it is not working. I cannot send original Korean characters if I send it is unreadable.

Comment: I am using [link](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) code. `get_respond` returns Statement.

Comment: In that case, I think `print(d.text)` or `print(d.text.decode())` should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what `python.run` does, since you won't share that code, but here's my version of the code, which is working fine:

**test.py**

```
print("안녕 세상")
```

**app.js**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('python3 test.py', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});

// Output:
// 안녕 세상
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the totally same issue on my project and now I finally found the answer.

I solved my problem by using these codes.

It works on windows (macOS and Linux, their default system encoding it 'utf8' so the issue doesn't happen).

I hope it might help you, too!

```
#in the python file that your javascript file will call by python-shell module put those code
import sys    
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

I found the hints from  [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) description.

[feature >Simple and efficient data transfers through stdin and stdout streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swQJa.png)

Comment: Better solution than accepted one because don't need to change from `python-shell` library to `child_process`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using **python-shell**.

Here is my solution:

The string after .encode('utf-8') is a binary string. So you need to print it on stdout directly.

in **test.py**, it print a utf-8 json which include some chinese char:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(json.dumps({"你好":"世界"}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
print() # print \n at ending to support python-shell in json mode
```

in **main.js**

```
let opt = {mode: 'json', pythonOptions: ['-u'], pythonPath: 'python', encoding: 'utf8'}

let pyshell = new PythonShell('lyric.py', opt);
pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

    console.log(message);  //*** The console msg may still wrong (still ���)
    let json = JSON.stringify(message);
    let fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', function () {
    }); //*** The output json file will be correct utf8 output
});
```

result:
[image]
This shows the msg is correctly receive in utf-8, because the json output is correct.
However console.log output apparently failed.
I don't know is there any way to fix console.log output. (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble in using data(string) from python in node js.

I solved this problem in this way:

Try **change default code page of Windows Console to UTF-8**, if your code page of Windows Console is not UTF-8.
(In my case default code page was CP949.)

In my case:

I got message like ������ 2���� ��������.

I tried encoding on online (http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/url/converter.html)

then I found my strings encoded cp949 -> decoded utf-8.

Comment: Please avoid using Answer section to post another Question.